# Matching & Non Matching records with single query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in which it contains duplicate data based on multiple columns.I am looking to select the matching data based on multiple columns and at the same time non matching based on another column.

```
CREATE TABLE #table1
(
  id   INT,
  code VARCHAR(5),
  type VARCHAR(5)
)


INSERT INTO #table1(id,code,type)
SELECT 1,'AA','T' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'AB','R' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'AC','T' UNION ALL
SELECT 1,'AA','K' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'AC','T' 

    
SELECT t.*
  FROM #table1 T
 INNER JOIN #table1 T2
    ON t.id = t2.id
   AND t.code = t2.code
   AND t.type <> t2.type
```

I tried by self join with matching fields equal and non matching fields not equal

Comment: Please don't use images, use table markup

Comment: And please show us your attempt

Comment: A `where exists ...` query is one option

Comment: Far too unprecise und unclear. Please put more effort in explaining what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SELECT t1.ID, t1.CODE, t1.TYPE
      FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table1 t2
        ON t1.ID = t2.ID
       AND t1.CODE = t2.CODE
       AND t1.TYPE <> t2.TYPE
```

This query will return the rows from `Table1` that have matching `ID` and `CODE` values but different `TYPE` values.